# Jquery "Object has no method"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I've noticed this question has been answered in relation to various developers jquery installations, however i have come across this error and i am trying to figure out what is conflicting/causing this error message to occur in my script. I have made attempts to install a jQuery carousel onto my site which i have used before on pervious sites, however something within my code is preventing this carousel to work. Does this have something to do with the HTML 5 boilderplate prototype?

Is there anyone out there that can pin-point this issue?

[Click here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/bodyworks/index.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue that you have is `jQuery is not defined` because you load it at the end of the document, and it should be the first to load before any jQuery plugins

in other word, this 2 scripts :

```
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ResponsiveSlides.js"></script>
```

must be after

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Dont move the modernizr,, pllease....it dont need jQuery and it is better in head

Comment: @mgraph i've tried swapping these scripts around and i'm getting the following message: "object has no method"

Answer (score 1):

ResponsiveSlides.js depends on jQuery. This should be loaded after jQuery

Leave Modernizr in the head. Per their site:

> "The reason we recommend placing Modernizr in the head is two-fold:
>   the HTML5 Shiv (that enables HTML5 elements in IE) must execute before
>   the body, and if you’re using any of the CSS classes that Modernizr
>   adds, you’ll want to prevent a FOUC."